# How to Display an Elements Property

Tags: reactjs

How can I display an element's name property on said element? For instance, in my code i want its name "1" to be displayed on it, but instead all I get on the element is the word hey.

```js
import React from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/react';

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Hey"
    };
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button> {this.state.name} </button>
    );
  }




}
export default Button;
import React from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/react';
import Button from './Button.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div id= "Background">
    
    <div id = "Display Screen" className = "Rows"> </div>
    
    <div id = "Row 1" className = "Rows"> 
      <Button name = "AC"> </Button>
      <Button name = "+/-"> </Button>
      <Button name = "%"> </Button>
      <Button name = "/"> </Button>
    </div>
    <div id = "Row 2" className = "Rows"> 
      <Button name = "7"> </Button>
      <Button name = "8"> </Button>
      <Button name = "9"> </Button>
      <Button name = "X"> </Button>
    </div>
    <div id = "Row 3" className = "Rows"> 
      <Button name = "4"> </Button>
      <Button name = "5"> </Button>
      <Button name = "6"> </Button>
      <Button name = "-"> </Button>
    </div>
    <div id = "Row 4" className = "Rows"> 
      <Button name = "1"> </Button>
      <Button name = "2"> </Button>
      <Button name = "3"> </Button>
      <Button name = "+"> </Button>
    </div>
    <div id = "Row 5" className = "Rows">
      <Button name = "0"> </Button>
      <Button name = "."> </Button>
      <Button name = "="> </Button>  
    </div>

    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Thanks. How can I display an element's name property on said element? For instance, in my code i want its name "1" to be displayed on it, but instead all I get on the element is the word hey. Thanks.

Comment: you just want to display the name property isn't it ? Why are you creating a state ?

Comment: what would be the alternative? but yes thats what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display the `name` property, you don't need to declare a state

```
function Button (props) {
  return <button>{props.name}</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let's say I wanted to keep the way I was doing things, how would I display the name state?

Comment: I don't understand, in your solution you are already displaying the name state property

Comment: but how come my code displays Hey instead of the actual name of the component?

Comment: replace `name: "Hey"` by `name: props.name`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `state` use `props`

```
<button>{this.props.name}</button>
```